# Правильно ли построено предложение со словом "всегда"?

Tags: пунктуация

Мама помогает *всегда* - когда, кажется, что нет выхода, когда теряешь веру и силы жить дальше.

Answer (score 4):

"Всегда" в этом предложении выступает в качестве обобщающего слова, после него лучше поставить двоеточие. Слово "кажется" здесь не вводное, перед ним запятая не нужна.

*Мама помогает всегда: когда кажется, что нет выхода, когда теряешь веру и силы жить дальше.*